# Ignore incomplete datasets with regex?

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

How can I ignore incomplete datasets when searching with regex?

I want to return the `IN_MEASUREMENT` items for a `FUNCTION`.

```
import re

sFileContent = '''
/begin FUNCTION

   foo
   "a.1.2.3       footext"
   /begin SUB_FUNK
      fooo foobar foobar
   /end SUB_FUNK

   FUNK_VERSION "a.1.2.3"

/end FUNCTION

/begin FUNCTION

   foobarbarbar
   "SSV-TAG 3.1.0-3.1.0 foobarbarbar tex text_tex"
   /begin SUB_FUNK
      foobarbarbarfoo foobarbarbarfooo foobarbarbarfoooo
   /end SUB_FUNK

   /begin IN_MEASUREMENT
      barbar barfoo
   /end IN_MEASUREMENT

   /begin OUT_MEASUREMENT
      barfoobar barbarfoo
   /end OUT_MEASUREMENT

   /begin LOC_MEASUREMENT
      loc_barfoobar barbarfoo_loc
   /end LOC_MEASUREMENT

   FUNK_VERSION "3.1"

/end FUNCTION'''

sSearch = r'/begin FUNCTION\s*(\S*)\s*(?:"[^"]*").*? /begin IN_MEASUREMENT\s*(.*?)\s*/end IN_MEASUREMENT.*?/end FUNCTION'
lMatches = re.findall(sSearch, sFileContent, re.S)

print(lMatches)
```

It is returning `[('foo', 'barbar barfoo')]`.

It should, however, return `[('foobarbarbar', 'barbar barfoo')]` since the first `FUNCTION` does not contain any `IN_MEASUREMENT`.
Can I solve this without using two concatenated regex searches (once for each `FUNCTION` and then in this searching for `IN_MEASUREMENT`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may make use of a tempered greedy token:

```
/begin FUNCTION\s*(\S*)\s*(?:"[^"]*")(?:(?!/begin FUNCTION).)*? /begin IN_MEASUREMENT\s*(.*?)\s*/end IN_MEASUREMENT.*?/end FUNCTION
#                                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Lhydod/1/)

The `(?:(?!/begin FUNCTION).)*?` pattern will match any char, 0 or more times, that does not start a `/begin FUNCTION` substring.

To make it work faster, I'd suggest unrolling the TGT construct as `[^/]*(?:/(?!begin FUNCTION)[^/]*)*`:

```
/begin FUNCTION\s*(\S*)\s*(?:"[^"]*")[^/]*(?:/(?!begin FUNCTION)[^/]*?)* /begin IN_MEASUREMENT\s*(.*?)\s*/end IN_MEASUREMENT.*?/end FUNCTION
#                                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

See [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Lhydod/3).

The `[^/]*(?:/(?!begin FUNCTION)[^/]*?)*` matches 0+ chars other than `/`, then 0 or more repetitions of `/` not followed with `begin FUNCTION` and then 0+ chars other than `/`, as few as possible.

Comment: Thank you. That does seem to work. Wow. Regex is very mysterious! However, the second version seems to need more steps and therefore should be slower, don't you agree?

Comment: So it basically works by "catching" the early `/end FUNCTION` and then searching for a new `/begin FUNCTION`, right?

Comment: @mrCarnivore The TGT does not allow to match across another `/begin FUNCTION`.